# Getting a strike through on windown.feature_progress in Eclipse android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I am getting a Red Strike through on Window progress bar. I am trying to convert a WEB into an app.

See pic for further detail.

[image]

```
    final Activity mActivity = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Adds Progrss bar Support
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.portal);


    // Makes Progress bar Visible
    getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webView1 );
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);     
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://cms.comsats.edu.pk:8092");


    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() 
    {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)  
        {
            //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
            mActivity .setTitle("Loading...");
            mActivity .setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded

            // Return the app name after finish loading
            if(progress == 100)
            {
                financialPortalActivity.setTitle(R.string.yourWebSiteName);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Did you hover your mouse over it?

Comment: What is your question?